# not catching PDOException in namespace

Tags: php, database, namespaces, pdo

I can't know how can i catch `PDOException` in the follow code,please tell me where throw exception in the follow code?

i have (directory) :

```
 - folder
     -1) b.php
     -2) c.php

 - autoloader
```

in the `b.php` :

```
<?php
namespace folder;
use folder as x;
require_once '../autoload.php';
class b{
    function __construct(){
        print("<p>you are in class b<p/>");
    }
}
$t=new x\c();
?>
```

and in `c.php`:

```
class c{
    function __construct(){
        print("<p>you are in class c<p/>");

        if(DB_TYPE == 'mysql')  
        $pdoString=DB_TYPE.':dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST;

        $pdoUsername=DB_USERNAME;
        $pdoPass='1';//DB_PASS; in this line I enter wrong password

    try{
            $this->pdo = new PDO($pdoString, $pdoUsername, $pdoPass);

    }catch(PDOException $e){ //we can't catch exception here!
        die('<p> Error DataBase Connection: '.$e->getMessage()."</p>");
    }
}
}
?>
```

I enter wrong password,i expect that have catch the exception in my `try catch` block but have this output:

```
 you are in class c

 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\folder\c.php:17 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\folder\c.php(17): PDO->__construct('mysql:dbname=kn...', 'root', '1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\folder\b.php(10): folder\c->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\folder\c.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are in a namespace. Hence, PHP will look for the namespaced class `folder\PDOException` and attempt to catch that (And fail).

To use the global namespace, simply add a backslash behind the class name:

```
catch (\PDOException $e) {
```

Comment: @NavidMafakheri: The global namespace is the default namespace. The one PHP uses when you don't specify anything using the `namespace` language construct. Read about namespaces on the PHP manual. http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: I don't understand why we have to use the backslash. The normal behaviour in namespaces is that PHP falls back to the default namespace in case the class has not been found. Why does that not happen when catching exceptions?

Comment: 4 years later and this answer has just saved me hours of work.That backslash has caught me out many times.