# PDO FetchAll returns an empty array but there is value in db

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I have a drop down box with multiple select . The dropdown looks like this:

```
 <select multiple class="form-control" name="batch_no[]"  id="batch_no" required onchange="getBatchCourseDetail();">
<option value="">-----------Select Your Batch----------</option>
<?php
foreach ($result as $res) 
{
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $res['batch_code']; ?>"><?php echo $res['batch_code']; ?></option>
<?php
 } ?>
</select>
```

In onchange function call i have the script like this:

```
function getBatchCourseDetail()
{
    var other = String($('#batch_no').val());
    var opts = [],
    opt;
    var split1 = other.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < split1.length; i++) 
    {
       opt = split1[i];
       opts.push(opt);
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: 'course_apply_batch_course_detail_ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 
      {
        batch_code: opts
      },
      success: function (data) 
      {
        //console.log(data);
        $('#batch_information_autofill').html(data);
      }
   });
}
```

In the ajax file that is in course_apply_course_detail_ajax.php page I retrieve all the values of the drop down .

course_apply_course_detail_ajax.php :

```
<?php
 require('classes/autoloader.php');
 $course_apply = new \Model\CourseApplyModel();
 $batch_code111=array();
 $batch_code111 = $_POST['batch_code'];
 $batch_code1 ="'" .implode("','",$batch_code111) ."'";

 $parameter = array(
    "batchcode" => $batch_code1,
    "status" => 0);

 $result11 =$course_apply->getBatchCourseDetail11($parameter);

 echo"<pre>";
 print_r($result11);
 echo"</pre>";
 exit;
 ?>
```

I will be getting the $batch_code1 values as : 'LATS-CHMB-1000','LATS-SA-1000','LATS-ABSE-1003' which is stored in the array variable 'batchcode'.

In Model My query looks like this:

```
 public function getBatchCourseDetail11($parameter)
{
 /* $QUERY1="SELECT start_date,end_date,course_code FROM batch WHERE
     batch_code IN('LATS-CHMB-1000','LATS-SA-1000','LATS-ABSE-1003') AND status =0"; */

  $query1="SELECT start_date,end_date,course_code FROM batch WHERE status =:status AND batch_code IN(:batchcode)";
  try{
        $result1=$this->dbh->prepare($query1);
        $result1->execute($parameter);
        $data11=$result1->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data11;
    }
    catch(\PDOException $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
        return false;
    }

}
```

When i try to print the return data i'm getting array() but the query is executing correctly in the phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance please help me to get solved from this issue.

Comment: What are you using escape backslash for?

Comment: @Maksim.T  you mean this line :  $course_apply = new \Model\CourseApplyModel(); Its to create an object for the class.

Comment: No, I mean when you form your arrays with PDO and catch an exception. I.e. catch(\PDOException $e)

Comment: @Maksim.T Please refer to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614484/not-catching-pdoexception-in-namespace . To catch the exception we need to put a backslash to the classname.

Comment: @Maksim.T When i tried to do like this  print_r($this->$result1->errorInfo());  die();  after the execute  I'm getting a fatal error .

Answer (score 0):

The query is your issue

```
$query1="SELECT start_date,end_date,course_code 
         FROM batch 
         WHERE status =:status 
           AND batch_code IN(:batchcode)";
```

it is not possible to substitute an arbitrary query part with a placeholder. So for a comma-separated placeholders, like IN(), you must create a set of ?'s manually and put them into the query:

In short we must create a syntax like `IN(?,?,?)` if you have 3 values you want in your `IN()` list and then pass the 3 paremeters to the prepare.

```
public function getBatchCourseDetail11($parameter)
{
    // generate the number of ? we need
    $ins  = str_repeat('?,', count($parameter['batchcode']) - 1) . '?';

    $query1="SELECT start_date,end_date,course_code 
             FROM batch 
             WHERE status = ?
               AND batch_code IN($ins)";
    try{
        $result1=$this->dbh->prepare($query1);

        $params[] = $parameter['status'];
        foreach ( $parameter['batchcode'] as $p ) {
            $params[] = $p;
        }

        $result1->execute($params);

        $data11=$result1->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $data11;
    }
    catch(\PDOException $e) {
        print_r($e);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I copied and used the code you provided but still an empty array is what i'm getting. I can assure you that i have values in db. I checked the query with PHPmyadmin and i can get those values successfully.

Comment: Are you sure you have set PDO into Exception mode, There may be a little syntax opps I cannot test this right now `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

Comment: the code you provided is the right one it shows no error but returns  empty.

Comment: the edited code wont work its showing error since the value in $parameter['batchcode'] is a string and if we want to use that in foreach we have to explode it first and then we can use it other than that its not possible.

Comment: I am still here thinking

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($parameter['batchcodes']);` in the function so I can see exactly what is being passed please. Add result to question

Comment: Yeah i did with my above code and i can see the values like 'LATS-CHMB-1000','LATS-SA-1000','LATS-ABSE-1003' . These values have to be passed in IN() which i thinks i'm doing it in the right way .

Comment: I have a test in progress I am getting the same situation, few mins while I work out my mistake

Comment: I hope Query i writtened inside the comment is right .

Comment: If i put a bad query in PDO returns empty array but does not throw an exception for the prep or execute I have to test `$stmt` after the prepare, could that be it, even with Exceptions set

Comment: I stored the comma separated values in a variable before the   query starts and passed that variable inside the IN() now execute the query . It will work fine.

Comment: That sounds like you have just opened up an SQL Injection vector.

Comment: Amended code to my second try, that is how I got it working here

Comment: yeah sql injection is possible need to validate while passing the values.

Comment: I tried your code but its showing error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() like this.

Comment: Yea... `batchcodes` should be `batchcode` typo fixed it